# Linux on external USB drive won't boot on other computers

Tags: linux, grub2, uuid

I have GNU/Linux (currently Fedora 26, but previously Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya) installed on an external hard drive alongside an NTFS partition I use for storage – and it boots perfectly on the computer I used to install it. However, when I try booting on a different computer with a different hard drive configuration it can't find the OS partitions and dumps me into GRUB Rescue with the error message `error: unknown filesystem`.

I suspect this is because GRUB searches for the partitions using labels such as `hdX,msdosY` (`X` and `Y` being integers seemingly corresponding to `sXY` labels such as `sda1` with `X` being a letter and `Y` being an integer), as the `menuentry`s in my `grub.cfg` uses them when setting the `root` variable – assuming that `grub.cfg` is the source for what's put in the MBR. My `/etc/default/grub` does not contain `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true`.

Could the solution to my problem be making GRUB search for the partitions using UUID – and if so: How would I go about making it do so?

---

EDIT: Here is the full `menuentry` for booting Fedora from my `grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry 'Fedora (4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64) 26 (Twenty Six)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os --unrestricted $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64-advanced-c1bcc95a-66a8-4bd3-ae64-42be8d83137e' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd3,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd3,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci3,msdos2 --hint='hd1,msdos2'  3483e8e8-38ab-4b47-aec4-1cb475c285d8
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3483e8e8-38ab-4b47-aec4-1cb475c285d8
    fi
    linux16 /vmlinuz-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64 root=UUID=c1bcc95a-66a8-4bd3-ae64-42be8d83137e ro rhgb quiet LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
    initrd16 /initramfs-4.11.8-300.fc26.x86_64.img
}
```

I would also prefer any solution not involving manual editing of `grub.cfg` as any changes made would be overwritten upon updating GRUB.

---

EDIT 2: After I got everything to work with GPT and Fedora 26 I decided I would switch back to Linux Mint as that was my original distro of choice. This, however, turned out not to work. After testing with several different distros (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS and openSUSE). All RPM-based distros worked, while none of the Debain-based ones did. openSUSE provides an option to enable/disable SecureBoot support, and when it was installed with this disabled I got the same results as I did with the Debian-based distros.

This does not make any sense to me, as I can verify that at least two of the computers I tested on had SecureBoot explicitly disabled, yet I couldn't boot neither the Debain-based distros nor openSUSE without SecureBoot support.

(To clarify: the RPM distros didn't boot either before I changed my hard drive to use a GPT.)

Comment: My guess is you have a `/boot` partition on an internal disk on the computer (and grub-install was done when that partition was mounted on `/boot`). Go to grub shell (press `c` on grub menu; not rescue shell so boot it in the computer where it works for this) and run `probe -u $root`. Jot down the UUID and then boot to the system and list UUIDs of all filesystems with `blkid` (as root) or `lsblk -f`, and see which drive the filesystem that has the UUID from grub shell is on.

Comment: The file system that has the UUID I got from GRUB Shell is on my external hard drive.

Comment: Does any of the computers (work or not work) has UEFI instead of BIOS? Is there a vfat EFI system partition on the external drive?

Comment: Also, if you explicitly choose to boot from the external drive on the BIOS/UEFI boot menu, does the probe command give you the same UUID?

Comment: @TomYan Both computers have UEFI, with support for legacy devices enabled.

Comment: @TomYan The way I have it set up forces me to manually boot from the UEFI boot menu.

Comment: But can you confirm both computers perform legacy booting to the drive? (i.e. no vfat EFI system partition on the drive)

Comment: @TomYan Looking at the drive in the Gnome Disk Utility shows no such partition.

Answer (score 1):

> error: unknown filesystem.

It worked on one system, not on the other, this means your grub probably does not search partitions by uuid.

> I suspect this is because GRUB searches for the partitions using labels such as hd0,msdos5, as the menu entries in my grub.cfg uses them – assuming that grub.cfg is the source for what's put in the MBR. My /etc/default/grub does not contain GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true.

This confirms my first impression. BTW, hd0,msdos5 is NOT a lable, but a disk specification that is outdated, now ... depending on many factors, hd0 could be any drive in your system ... more so, when you switch computers.

I have the following:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=<someUUID> ro  quiet nomodeset
```

I use `nomodeset` because some motherboards don't like Linux changing modes.

Check to see if the root partition has uuid and use that in grub, as mentioned above.

Comment: The `menuentry` for booting Fedora 26 already uses the UUID. I have updated my question with the full `menuentry`. I would also prefer a method not involving manually editing `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TomYan bringing EFI partitions to my attention a relatively simple solution became apparent.

First, I backed up all the data on my external hard drive before completely reformating it and making a GPT with `fdisk` instead of an MBR which it had previously. After doing this all that was left was to reinstall the distro in UEFI mode. It now boots perfectly on all the computers I have tried so far.

---

EDIT: This only solves the issue when booting RPM-based distros.